# iTextSharp - fdfWriter access to AcroFields to Set Field Property

Tags: itext

I need to update the FDF request Input Steam before saving it, programmatically on the server side. I am using the iTextSharp library.  The FdfReader gets the data fine and I can move it to the writer but there is no AcroFields property on the FdfWriter. And the AcroFields property on the FdfReader is ReadOnly, so I can't do that before setting the fields.

I need to be able to set a field's property to hidden. Like this:

**VB.Net**

```
Dim Reader As FdfReader = New FdfReader(Request.InputStream)
Dim Writer As FdfWriter = New FdfWriter

Writer.SetFields(Reader)
Reader.Close()

Writer.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty("Key", "setflags", PdfFormField.FLAGS_HIDDEN, Nothing)

'  (add Save to File here)
```

But *Writer.AcroFields* does not exits. How are field properties set with the FdfWriter?

Answer (score 0):

> How are field properties set with the FdfWriter?

They are not.
The object that allows you to retrieve and fill in fields throug code is the `PdfStamper`.
Have a look at this example: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-save-xfdf-file-pdf-file

Comment: Unfortunately the XFDF format does not allow to set field properties. This was what I was planning to do until I found out that Adobe did not put flag attributes on the field element.

I need to read a FDF file and create a new one. And the PdfStamper doesn't allow that without an actual PDF.

I'm afraid I will have to write a .Net wrapper around the old FdfApp ActiveX object.